# Meteor barbatus:typescript gives error on existing project

Tags: meteor

Have a Meteor project (1.4.3.2) that previously ran on Fedora, but getting an error now. Similar errors occur after update to 1.4.4.1. Any suggestions on how to fix this? Results of meteor list follow.

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Errors prevented startup:

   While processing files with barbatus:typescript (for target web.browser):

   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/meteor-typescript/utils.js:91:12:
   false == true
   at exports.assertProps
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/meteor-typescript/utils.js:91:12)
   at createCSResult
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/meteor-typescript/compile-service.js:125:3)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/meteor-typescript/index.js:174:22
   at Cache.CCp.get
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/meteor-typescript/cache.js:167:19)
   at TSBuild.emit
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/meteor-typescript/index.js:168:31)
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:135:30
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:324:29
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:44:16
   at packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:142:7
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:182:20
   at replenish
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:317:21)
   at
   /home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:328:15
   at Object.async.forEachLimit.async.eachLimit
   (/home/bobd/.meteor/packages/barbatus_typescript/.0.6.5_1.1c3b5xq++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.typescript.os/npm/node_modules/meteor/barbatus_typescript-compiler/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:221:35)
   at TypeScriptCompiler.processFilesForTarget
   (packages/barbatus:typescript-compiler/typescript-compiler.js:127:11)


=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.
```

**meteor list**

```
$ meteor list
accounts-password          1.3.4* Password support for accounts
alanning:roles             1.2.16  Authorization package for Meteor
angular2-compilers         0.6.6  Angular 2 Templates, HTML and TypeScript compilers for Meteor
dispatch:mocha-phantomjs   0.1.9  Run package or app tests with Mocha+PhantomJS and report all results in the server console
es5-shim                   4.6.15  Shims and polyfills to improve ECMAScript 5 support
hwillson:stub-collections  1.0.3  Stub out Meteor collections with in-memory local collections.
meteor-base                1.0.4  Packages that every Meteor app needs
mobile-experience          1.0.4  Packages for a great mobile user experience
mongo                      1.1.16  Adaptor for using MongoDB and Minimongo over DDP
practicalmeteor:mocha      2.4.5_6  Write package tests with mocha and run them in the browser or from the command line with spacejam.
reactive-var               1.0.11  Reactive variable
shell-server               0.2.3  Server-side component of the `meteor shell` command.
standard-minifier-css      1.3.4  Standard css minifier used with Meteor apps by default.
standard-minifier-js       1.2.3* Standard javascript minifiers used with Meteor apps by default.
tracker                    1.1.2  Dependency tracker to allow reactive callbacks
xolvio:cleaner             0.3.1  Gives you methods to clear your Mongo database and collections for testing purposes


* New versions of these packages are available! Run 'meteor update' to try to update those packages to their latest versions. If your packages cannot be
  updated further, try typing `meteor add <package>@<newVersion>` to see more information.
```